# Back EMF and Source EMF, stabilizing current?

Tags: voltage, current, constant-current

In a circuit where there is change in a magnetic flux, Back EMF is induced.

When back EMF is increases it reduces the source EMF( or oppose it) and therefore, the current is reduced, in order to stabilize current as it was before back EMF was created to reduce current, what can be done?

Note: Power can be changed.
So what might be the solution? 
Increase the resistance so that source EMF would be higher than the back EMF, therefore... stabilizing current at the cost for higher power?

Comment: I can't make sense of this gibberish.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Wow, note to self, never write something when you're extremely tired. Sorry there, I corrected the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When back EMF (such as from a motor) increases it **doesn't** reduce the source EMF (because that is a voltage source and is fixed by the power supply generating it). What the back emf does is act in opposition to the source voltage so that if back emf increases the current taken by the (say) motor decreases.

Typically a motor with no mechanical load will produce a high back emf and this keeps the motor current small - this is logical because on no-load the motor current should be small. As the mechanical load on the motor increases, the back emf decreases and more current is taken.

I'm trying to tease a question from the words and misinformation posted and hopefully I've answered the correct question.

Comment: Okay, can we increase source EMF so that it acts against the back EMF as it increases, so that current is not changed and stays the same?

Comment: @Key - it's called a constant current generator and is an op-amp, a transistor and a resistor - it raises the source voltage to keep the current constant.

Comment: Just wanted to know if the principle will allow such an idea...

Comment: If it's to do with DC motor speed and torque control then this is commonly done.

Comment: Andy, not necessarily... its just the principle of increasing source-emf so that back-emf will not reduce the source-current on any circuit.

Comment: @Key I no your question isn't necessarily "DC motor speed control", I'm just saying that these sort of methods are used in DC motor speed control.

Comment: Andy, I have a confusing situation. If we increase resistance of the system don't we reduce the current? I mean, if we increased resistance to increase source voltage to oppose back-emf and allow current to be stable... wouldn't source current be decreased due to the back-emf and therefore; having much less current due to the increased resistance?

Comment: Source emf - back emf = total emf, and the increases resistance is a based on the Source emf, that is higher than total emf.

Comment: @key I have no idea what you are saying and how it relates.

Comment: How can a constant current source stabilize current, when the source voltage is reduced by the back-emf? How is it even possible to have the same current, when resistance & voltage are varying in a constant current source?

Comment: I apologize for the confusing texts.

Comment: The source voltage is fixed. That is a fact - it cannot be reduced - it is what it is - it's the back emf that varies and this variation governs the current flow variations.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I went through this multiple times because my goal is to make current(100Amps) the same regardless of large/small back-emf's induced due to changing magnetic flux. If the principle allows this to do so, then its good to know its possible to make current stable regardless of back-emf.

Comment: Andy, If a circuit has low resistance(0.01ohms) and back-emf is equal to 30V, large amounts of power is needed to maintain the same current of 100A. Because 0.01Ohmsx100A = 1V... And for a power supply to go from 1V to 30V that's massive amounts of power isn't it? 30^2/0.01 = 6kW, from initial 100W.

Comment: It is possible to maintain the current to be the same, but at the cost of "large" amounts of power.

Comment: That's what happens unfortunately. The current source has to be able to use a large voltage supply in order to counteract the back emf level. Complexity in the circuit can reduce the power dissipated but it's not a trivial circuit that can keep power dissipated low.

Comment: There could be a solution, where massive amounts of power is not needed: DC/DC converter could be one, also a high internal resistance power supply. I dunno, I'll research this more.

Comment: What you should look for is a buck converter that has a constant current output with a voltage output compliance as high as maybe 40 volts (if 35V were your back emf). Constant current buck converters are used for driving long strings of LEDs so it is something that has a reasonable solution but might a little bit of switching noise be a problem or, is this for a coil-gun where it don't really matter?

Comment: Well as long as I won't have to apply HUGE power I'll certainly try to find other solutions. I believe I can solve this problem without using enormous power, sure add a bit of power of course but power that is need for the circuit. The example I posted earlier, the additional power is 60 times more than the initial power, unreasonable waste. It's more of a study, trying to maintain the same current over changing potential differences induced by a magnetic field.

Comment: Hi Andy, what do you think of the idea of using another conductor(with the first) oriented in the same changing magnetic field to induce equal EMF's but cancel each other out? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134599/two-conductors-in-a-magnetic-field-canceling-each-others-emf?noredirect=1#comment272231_134599

Comment: I think this idea could work but is sufficiently evolved from the original as to warrant another question. More people are going to contribute too hopefully. You can mark this question as answered if you think it is.

Comment: It certainly is!