# Two conductors in a magnetic field, canceling each other's EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism

If two conductors are in a changing magnetic field, oriented the same in the field, and they induced equal EMF's, can their wiring be oriented in a way that they can cancel each other's induced EMF?

So that that $$\epsilon_t= \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2$$

Similar to [twisted pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair) concept.

Comment: Sure, think of two similar coils but wound in opposite directions.  (coils actually don't need to be similar.. just have equal turns * area)

Comment: They can, but they can't both occupy the same physical space simultaneously so you can't get perfect cancellation under real conditions.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Well they are both in the same magnetic field, they should be getting the same (flux change) over time. So, if conductor 1 induces V conductor 2 should have -V equal to V, therefore V(tot)=0! :D, or the intended experiment should allow them to be in the same physical space. It's like having two conductors in a field attached to each other. But their wires are in opposition.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold They are both oriented in the same way in the magnetic field, still they could cancel it other out?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, We use the turns*area trick to help reduce interfering B fields in this, http://teachspin.com/instruments/earths_field_NMR/index.shtml  The big outer coil has the same turns area as the smaller pickup coil in the center.  You never get to "perfect", but good enough is often enough :^)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold what if there is a load to the circuit? The two conductors wired in opposition without a load will cancel, but if a load is added to the circuit the current will flow?

Comment: @Key, Re: Circuit with load.  That won't matter, the same current has to flow through both coils.  So the drop across the load from each coil will be the same... assuming equal emfs.  (For the image linked to in spehro's comment we resonate both coils with a parallel capacitor.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Thank you, I was actually thinking of using this concept in a circuit. Some induced-emf is created and was wondering ifI could use another conductor and cancel them out or somewhat cancel them out.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Thank you, I'm actually using this concept

Comment: @Key, Does one coil see a signal?  The trick is keeping the signal much bigger in one coil.  (you can drop me an email.  gherold (at sign) with the website listed on my profile.)

Comment: Strange, I didn't complete that whole comment. I'm using this concept in a circuit that has two conductors in a changing magnetic field, and need them to cancel each other out without "effecting" the circuit. Will contact you with the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the things coaxial cable and twisted pair cable try to do.  Ideally, each conductor sees the same magnetic field and thereby has the same EMF generated end to end.  This affects the common mode voltage, but not the differential mode voltage.  Systems that use such cables are usually designed to use the differential voltage only, and allow for some common mode offset.

Twisted pair ethernet is a common example of this.  The ends are transformer coupled, so only the differential mode voltage matters.  The common mode voltage can be up to whatever the insulation of the cable and the transformers at each end can handle.  If I remember right, the ethernet standard requires ends to be able to handle 100s or volts of common mode offset, or maybe 1000 volts.  I don't remember the exact number, but it's enough to allow one device riding on a 240 V power line with the other device tied to ground.

Comment: Can this idea be a part of a circuit with other power sources and components? I tend to use this concept in a circuit, where two conductor cancel out induce EMF.